# go-yaml v3 encoder writing tag of merge node ( !!merge) in output

Tags: go, yaml

I am trying to parse a Yaml file with go-yaml v3 and do some modifications on the YAML nodes but when I am writing back the content to a file, the yaml encoder adds an extra merge tag (`!!merge`) wherever i have used `<<`

```
func main() {

    sourceYaml := `
demo:
  - name: some_name
    location:
      country:
        meta_data: &meta_data
          name: some_place
          description: "name of a place"
      <<: *meta_data`

    node := yaml.Node{}
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(sourceYaml), &node)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer
    yamlEncoder := yaml.NewEncoder(&b)
    yamlEncoder.SetIndent(2)
    err = yamlEncoder.Encode(&node)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println(b.String())
    err = os.WriteFile("test.yaml", b.Bytes(), 0o664)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

This will print

```
demo:
  - name: some_name
    location:
      country:
        meta_data: &meta_data
          name: some_place
          description: "name of a place"
      !!merge <<: *meta_data
```

I was expecting to get the same yaml printed but there was a difference in the output because of extra `!!merge` string.

How can i remove this !!merge string from my generated file? I would consider a string replacement as the last solution but I want to avoid that first because my YAML can contain comments as well and I don't want to change that.

Answer (score 0):

The tag is [automatically filled by go-yaml](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Node):

> When decoding, this field will always be set to the resolved tag,
> **even when it wasn't explicitly provided** in the YAML content.

Technically go-yaml is not wrong to output the tag, however their docs state

> [the tag] will only be serialized into the representation if TaggedStyle is used or
> the implicit tag diverges from the provided one.

„The implicit tag“ *is* `!!merge` (as your code shows) so go-yaml shouldn't output it. You could file a bug report for this.

In the meantime, you can remove the tag after unmarshaling with a function like this:

```golang
func removeMerge(node *yaml.Node) {
    if node.Tag == "!!merge" {
        node.Tag = ""
    }
    for _, child := range node.Content {
        removeMerge(child)
    }
}
```

[Full example based on your code at Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/8zJc7bBUaVr)